# IOS Obj C: Initializing multiple IBOutlet instances with same values

Tags: objective-c, ios, iboutlet

I am having some trouble getting my head around how I can init a class and pass identical init params to multiple instances. I can get it to work with 1 outlet (instance1). But how can I also get it to work with instance 2 without re-writing the variables for each instance?

ViewController.h:

```
#import "CustomClass.h"

@interface MYViewController : UIViewController

@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet CustomClass *instance1;
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet CustomClass *instance2;

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "CustomClass.h"

@implementation MYViewController;

@synthesize instance1, instance2;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    instance1.variable1 = option1;
    instance1.variable2 = 4.5;
    instance1.variable3 = instance1.value;
    [instance1 addTarget:self action:@selector(instance1DidChange) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A loop with some KVC should do it for you...

```
@implementation MYViewController;

@synthesize instance1, instance2;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    for (int i = 0; i =< 1; i++) {
        MyClass *newInstanceVariable = [[MyClass alloc] init];
        newInstanceVariable.variable1 = option1;
        newInstanceVariable.variable2 = 4.5;
        newInstanceVariable.variable3 = instance1.value;
        [newInstanceVariable addTarget:self action:@selector(instance1DidChange) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        instanceVariableName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"instance%i",i];
        [self valueForKey:instanceVariableName] = newInstanceVariable;
    }
}
```

Should be pretty close to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you want to add the instances to an NSSet or NSArray and either iterate over that or use [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) to set the values. If these outlets are conceptually a group of things rather than just a bunch of independent objects that happen to have the same initial values, you can use IBOutletCollection instead of IBOutlet to have them all kept in an array to begin with.